# Batch select and iterate mysql results in java to decrease waiting time

Tags: java, mysql

I have made an application that visualizes locations with diatom species found at those locations.
My problem is, it's extremely slow. When 128 locations are found, it takes roughly 130 seconds to visualise. With 6000+ locations in my database, this would be way too slow. The reason for this speed is the way I'm retrieving all diatoms found at a location for each location. I am opening a connection to the database for each iteration and I assume that's where a lot of time is lost. Is there a way to speed this up? I have looked at `addBatch` and  `executeBatch`. But how do I iterate the results if I would use batches. Or is there a different way I should be doing this?

For each Location object in listOfLocations, I use the Location object.getName to retrieve all diatom species at that location from the database and add those as a hashmap back to the same Location object that is in listOfLocations.

```java
try (Connection connection = DbConnection.getConnection()) {
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    for (int x = 0; x <= listOfLocations.size() - 1; x++) {
        String query = "select diatom.species from entry" +
                " join location on location.name = entry.name" +
                " join diatom on diatom.taxonKey = entry.taxonKey" +
                " where location.name = ? AND diatom.species != \"\"";
        assert connection != null;
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, listOfLocations.get(x).getName());
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        HashMap<String, String> diatomHashmap = new HashMap<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            //checks if diatom species was in the input
            //of the program to assign present/notpresent
            if (diatomArray.contains(rs.getString(1))) {
                diatomHashmap.put(rs.getString(1), "Present");
            } else if (!diatomArray.contains(rs.getString(1))) {
                diatomHashmap.put(rs.getString(1), "notPresent");
            }
            listOfLocations.get(x).setDiatoms(diatomHashmap);
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
return listOfLocations;
```

To summarize: how can i open the connection with the database, execute all queries in one go and iterate the results to readd them to the Location objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should phrase this as a `WHERE IN (...)` query

```java
String query = "SELECT d.species " +
    "FROM entry e " +
    "INNER JOIN location l ON l.name = e.name " + 
    "INNER JOIN diatom d ON d.taxonKey = e.taxonKey " +
    "WHERE d.species != '' AND l.name IN ";

StringBuilder whereIn = new StringBuilder("(?");
for (int i=0; i < listOfLocations.size()-1; ++i) {
    whereIn.append(", ?");
}
whereIn.append(")");
query += whereIn.toString();

preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
for (int i=1; i <= listOfLocations.size(); ++i) {
    preparedStatement.setString(i, listOfLocations.get(i-1).getName());
}

ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    // iterate and process result set here...
}
```

To be explicit here, the above code generates a `WHERE IN (...)` clause with the same number of `?` placeholders as there are locations in your `listOfLocations` list.  So, assuming it had 5 placeholders, the `WHERE` clause would be this:

```sql
WHERE d.species != '' AND l.name IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

We then iterate the list of locations, and bind each value to a `?` placeholder above.  This approach avoids the multiple queries, because now we can cover every location with just a single query.

Comment: But unless i'm mistaken, this will add all diatoms from every location to every location object as in, every location object gets the same list of diatoms, even if the diatom isn't found at that location in the database.

Comment: How you process the result set is up to you, and you can't expect most readers to figure out that logic based on only what you posted above.  In any case, you're currently doing one query per location.  That's inefficient, and you should be using `WHERE IN (...)`.

Comment: Well, half my question is how to iterate the result. Because I did know about ```WHERE IN```, but I moved to single queries because I didn't know how I could iterate the result and write the right results to the right Location object.
Are you able to help me with the result set iteration or would it be more wise for me to dedicate a seperate question to that part?

More information:
listOfLocations contains Location objects with String name. I add to the Location object the hashmap keys of diatoms that are found there and for values present or not based on the input in ```diatomArray```.

Comment: @matthewjava Your original title mentions decreasing waiting time.  My answer alone should already get your performance in a place where you can live with it.  If you have issues with the result set, then maybe ask in another question or just resolve on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that you have these indexes:

```
location:  INDEX(name)
entry:     INDEX(name, taxonKey)
diatom:    INDEX(taxonKey, species)
```

If you still have issues, please provide

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE -- for each table
the generated SELECT
EXPLAIN SELECT ...
```